# UIWebView loads payment gateway(stripe) page url in my app, will Apple approve it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, uiwebview, stripe-payments

I am developing a app for viewing Live video and Recorded video, it contains UIWebView in application Login screen. That UIWebView leads to buy the surveillance camera subscription. We are using Third party payment gateway (stripe) for payment process. Without using In-App purchase,will it affect the Apple review guidelines?

Comment: Based on what you're selling you **have** to use IAP and you will be rejected if you use Stripe directly. https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-and-stripe-tos-and-fees

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are making Stripe Token by yourself or just sending details on server and server is making the transaction.

Stripe's transaction is usually server based, so it doesn't matter.

Plus, I want to give you an advice,

If you want to use Stripe in iOS apps, integrate it with [Apple pay](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#applepay). As user will trust the application and Apple will handle transaction more conveniently.

Comment: When user click the buy button in UIWebView it will redirect to safari browser to open the third party payment gateway(stripe) webpage. It will violates the Apple guidelines or not?